# How to access DropDownList Control's selected value inside GridView ItemTemplate using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I have GridView with DropDownList items inside its ItemTemplate.

Now, I want to access the SelectedValue of each DropDownList control inside GridView using JavaScript.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show the browsers source code

Comment: No, I don't have browsers source code.

Answer (score 1):

Im just guessing this is what you asking?

you can easly pass reference by using "this"

```
function whatsBeenSelected(optionSelected){
  var selectedValue = optionSelected.value; // give you access to what value has been selected
  alert(optionSelected.value);
}
</script>
```

and for your combo boxs in the select add a event handler with the function name example generated from your gridview.

```
<select name="price" onchange="return whatsBeenSelected(this)">
<option value="Select Something">Select</option>
<option value="10">Price $10</option>
<option value="24">Price $24</option>
</select>


<select name="age" onchange="return whatsBeenSelected(this)">
<option value="No Colour selected">Select</option>
<option value="red">Color red</option>
<option value="blue">Price blue</option>
</select>
```

let me know if this is what i think you are meaning